# Ajax is not calling the php file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the price of Item after selecting the item in a dropdown. I have used ajax calls but my code is not going inside `$.ajax({...`. What is wrong with my code?

I have used alert in the php file but nothing displays, which means my code is not calling php file.

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $("#puja_name2").on('change',function()
   { 
    var id=$(this).val();
    var data = 'id='+ id;
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "../ajax_price.php",
     data: data,
     cache: false,
     success: function(html)
     {
      $("#puja_price2").html(data);
    
     }
    
    });
   });
 </script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
  Puja Name<span class="font-red">* </span>:
  </label>
                                
  <select class="form-control" name="puja_name2" id="puja_name2"  data-validetta="required">
   <option value="">Select Puja Name</option>
    <?php
                
    $SQL_STATEMENT_puja = $DatabaseCo->dbLink->query("SELECT * FROM puja_type ");
   while($DatabaseCo->dbRow = mysqli_fetch_object($SQL_STATEMENT_puja)){
    ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $DatabaseCo->dbRow->puja_id; ?>" ><?php echo $DatabaseCo->dbRow->puja_name; ?></option>
   <?php                                 
    } 
                                ?>
 </select>
 </div>
      
 <div class="form-group">
  <label> Price <span class="font-red">* </span>:</label>
  <select  id="puja_price2" >
                                    
 </select>           
 </div>
```

Comment: do you really have the `<script>` where it is now (inside the js function)??

Comment: just do correct about the syntax of <script> tag buddy

Comment: and if this is the complete php script, it will throw at least 3 errors. And an alert in the php file won't actually alert anything.

Comment: Have you used a browser's dev tool to see what URL the ajax is actually trying to reach?

Comment: The JS will throw errors, too, when it hits the HTML `<!--` comments.

Comment: _“I have used alert in php file but nothing displays, It means my code is not calling php file”_ - no, it does not necessarily mean that - because script elements inserted dynamically via innerHTML do not get executed. As just mentioned, you should use your browser dev tools as the primary debugging tool here, and not alerts or other stuff like that.

Comment: You're targeting `'$(#puja_name')` in your ajax call but I can't see where it is defined in your php file. If you want to initiate the ajax call when the option is changed on the select element you'll need to change your selector to `$("#puja_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this in your JS code.


<script src="jquery.js"></script>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#puja_id').change(function(){

                var id = $(this).val();
                var data = 'id='+id;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../ajax_price.php",       
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    success:function(res){
                    $('#puja_price2').html(res);
                    }
                });

    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: I have made suggested changes still no luck please help me to sort this out

Comment: @DJ Reddy, This Comment is for JeanPaul98, then why u comment me?

Answer (score 1):

You must change in jquery `puja_name` to `puja_id`:

```
$("#puja_id").on('change',function()
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things wrong with your code bud:

**1)** You have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
<script>
//code
</script>
}
```

What your code should look like is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
//code
});
</script>
```

If you need to add comments in your JS code, DO NOT use `<!-- -->`. Instead use `//` like you see in my code above.

**2)** You need to change in your jquery `puja_name` to `puja_id` because your `<select></select>` id is `puja_id` so:
this 
`$("#puja_name").on('change',function() {`
turns to this
`$("#puja_id").on('change',function() {`

**3)** I'm not the greatest at SQL statements but I do feel that using the code below would help you even more (you don't HAVE to).

```
<?php

$SQL_STATEMENT_puja = "SELECT * FROM puja_type WHERE status='APPROVED' ORDER BY puja_name ASC";
$DatabaseCo = $conn->query($SQL_STATEMENT_puja);

$puja=$row['puja']; //This should actually be $puja=$row['puja_id'];

while($row = $DatabaseCo->fetch_assoc()) {

?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['puja_id']; ?>" <?php if($row['puja_id']==$puja) { echo "selected"; } ?>><?php echo $row['>puja_name']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

**4)** In your JQuery you have it as `$("#puja_price").html(html);` it should be `$("#puja_price").html(data);`

**5)** I also see that you have it as `#puja_price` but there's nothing in your html that has the `id` of `puja_price` so

I recommend changing this 

`$("#puja_price").html(html);` 
to
`$("#puja_price2").html(data);`

**6)** Your JQuery code is 
`$.ajax
({`

When it should be: `$.ajax({`

**Full code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
    Puja Name<span class="font-red">* </span>:
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="puja_id" id="puja_id" data-validetta="required">
        <option value="">Select Puja Name</option>
        <?php
            //If you already have the connection setup you don't need to add this
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "username";
            $password = "password";
            $dbname = "myDB";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $SQL_STATEMENT_puja = "SELECT * FROM puja_type WHERE status='APPROVED' ORDER BY puja_name ASC";
            $DatabaseCo = $conn->query($SQL_STATEMENT_puja);

            $puja=$row['puja'];

            while($row = $DatabaseCo->fetch_assoc()) {

        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['puja_id']; ?>" <?php if($row['puja_id']==$puja) { echo "selected"; } ?>><?php echo $row['>puja_name']; ?></option>
        <?php

            }

        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Price <span class="font-red">* </span>:
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="puja_price2" name="puja_price2" disabled>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#puja_id").on('change',function() {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var data = 'id='+ id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../ajax_price.php",
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#puja_price2").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Let me know if the changes work for you